# Android get click or not google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an application using google map v2. In this app user click on map and i get the lat& long . If user not clicked on map then how i force to him for that he must click on map before going forward. I want to show him alert box there . please help me.

Comment: You cannot force users to click on your map. They can always close the app. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the alert to the user as it comes to the activity call the below method in `onCreate()` as below :

```
private void showAlert()
{
AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            SurpriseSetting.this);
                    ab.setTitle("Hello!!");
                    ab.setMessage("Please Click on Map");
                    ab.setNeutralButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {

                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    ab.show();
  }
```

Or you can `Toast`

```
 Toast.makeText(m_context, "Please click on Map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I suggest you to show the toast is the better option to show such kind of indications to the user.

**EDITED:**

To implement click event on Map you have to extend `SupportMapFragment` or `MapFragment`. In `onCreateView()` you have to wrap your `MapView` in a customized `FrameLayout` (in example below it is the class `TouchableWrapper`), in which you intercepts touch events and recognizes whether the map is tapped or not. If your `onCameraChange` gets called, just check whether the map view is pressed or not (in example below this is the variable `mMapIsTouched`).

Example code:

UPDATE 1:

- return original created view in `getView()`
- use `dispatchTouchEvent()` instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent()`

Customized `FrameLayout`:

```
private class TouchableWrapper extends FrameLayout {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    switch (ev.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mMapIsTouched = true;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mMapIsTouched = false;
        break;
        }

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    }
```

In your customized `MapFragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mOriginalContentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

    mTouchView = new TouchableWrapper(getActivity());
    mTouchView.addView(mOriginalContentView);

    return mTouchView;
}

@Override
public View getView() {
    return mOriginalContentView;
}
```

In your camera change callback method:

```
private final OnCameraChangeListener mOnCameraChangeListener = new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        if (!mMapIsTouched) {
            refreshClustering(false);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: thanx for answer i know that how to show alert dialog. but i want to show it when user not click on map .

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if you don't have lat/lng(i.e. user has not clicked on map) all other actions should just show any alert msg or toast saying "u must click on the map before u do something".

So on any action other then click on map u can just check if lat/long is null then show alert.

Answer (score 0):

you can show a **toast** or **Notification** unless user check in.
By showing notification you can get better result.